# How to center an after pseudo-element above it's parent responsively?

Tags: css, vue.js, sass, pseudo-element

I'm attempting to make a responsive tooltip and have no hardcoded widths or anything on the parent.

This seems pretty straightforward, but I am not able to properly center the after element because of the fact that there is already a `transform: translateY(10px)` attribute on it.

I'm not able to do the normal `left:50%; top:50%; transform: translate(-50%, -50%)'` I've seen online because I already have a transform attribute in there.

Is this the location of the problem? Or is there another spot I should be looking?

If anyone has any tips or pointers please let me know!

Also, I hope it's no problem that it's in vue; everything should be handled in the style section anyway.

Cheers!

[**CodeSandbox Example**](https://codesandbox.io/s/tooltip-vue3-qygibg)

Tooltip.vue

```
<script lang="ts">
import { defineComponent, computed } from 'vue'

export default defineComponent({
  props: {
    text: { type: String, default: 'Pop!' },
    backgroundColor: { type: String, default: '#000' },
    textColor: { type: String, default: '#fff' },
  },
  setup(props) {
    const text = computed(() => props.text)
    return { text }
  },
})
</script>
<template>
  <span :data-tooltip="text">
    <slot />
  </span>
</template>

<style lang="sass">
[data-tooltip]
  position: relative
  cursor: default
  &:after
    position: absolute
    width: max-content
    // left: calc(50% )
    bottom: 125%
    text-align: center
    box-sizing: border-box
    display: flex
    justify-content: center

    content: attr(data-tooltip)
    color: v-bind(textColor)
    background: v-bind(backgroundColor)
    padding: 8px
    border-radius: 1em
    font-weight: bold
    white-space: nowrap

    visibility: hidden
    opacity: 0
    transform: translateY(10px)
    transition: all 400ms
    // transition: opacity 500ms, transform 500ms
  &:hover::after
    opacity: 1
    visibility: visible
    transform: translateY(0)
</style>
```

Comment: fyi, you can chain transform properties if you write them at once: `transform: translateY(10px) translate(-50%, -50%);`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The `:after` pseudo element is naturally left-aligned with its parent element, and since its width is wider than the `<span>` parent, it looks off center.

A quick fix is to make the `:after` pseudo element and `<span>` have the same width so that they're perfectly aligned:

```html
<style lang="sass">
[data-tooltip]
  &:hover::after
    width: 100%
</style>
```

[demo](https://codesandbox.io/s/centering-pseudo-element-with-its-parent-nfth05)

[image: screenshot]

Comment: As always Tony, great fix and explaination. Thanks again!